# How can i register a Receiver in a service?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I have to register a receiver that it's not in the same class. I mean, i have a service:

**service.java**

```
public class service extends Service {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        checkPref();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    private void checkPref() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service.this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Context");
        notificationBuilder.setTicker("TickerText");
        notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_icon);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, service.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and the **MyScheduleReceiver.java**

```
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Restart service every 30 min
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 30 * 1000 * 4;// 1800000 ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, service.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

Now i have to register a receiver like:

```
registerReceiver(//thereceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

inside the onCreate. How can i do it? I think that in `//thereceiver` i have to write `MyScheduleReceiver` but of course if i write in the onCreate inside the service it can't find it. How can i do? Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do? You have a service that registers a notification and within that notification you're starting the service again? Actually you'll send an intent to it, but seems to me it's pointless what you're doing in `MyScheduleReceiver`. Also, `service#checkPref` doesn't seem to me to create the Intent properly as it doesn't point to an `Activity` class.

Comment: Simply what i whant is that on battery changed the notification appears. Right now the notification starts only on BOOT_COMPLETED declared in the manifest but if i want to show the notification for example on battery changed how can i do? I think i have to declare the intent programmatically in the java right? i can't only change from `BOOT_COMPLETED` to `BATTERY_CHANGED`.. doesn't work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
registerReceiver(yourReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"));
```

You might will need to add the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
```

in your Manifest file